# How to make bootstrap work with Spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bootstrap-4

I created bootstrap html files in Bootstrap studio;
The structure as follows:
[image]

Then I moved root all these files to WEB-INF/view folder in Spring project end change them to jsp format.

I have a controller that maps 'localhost:8080/greeting' url to index.jsp

This how the page is supposed to look:
[image]

And this is how it actually looks:
[image]

Just to be honest, I have no idea how to include bootstrap in my spring project, so I don't ask to explain everything to me, but I'd love if someone could give me advice how to make this working.

Here's my greeting.jsp file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background: #000514;">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Dashboard - Logiweb Brand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css">
</head>

<body id="page-top" style="background: rgb(0,0,0);">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper" style="background: #000514;">
            <div class="text-break text-left" id="content" style="background: #000514;"></div>
        </div><a class="border rounded d-inline scroll-to-top" href="#page-top"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" style="color: var(--pink);background: #d70884;">
        <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">First Item</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Second Item</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Third Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">Dropdown </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First Item</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second Item</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Third Item</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you move the ```assets``` folder along with the ```html``` files to ```WEB-INF/view``` folder?

Comment: @Modo Yes, and I can see that html files are able to see assets folder

Comment: Then use this ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/name-of-file.css">```

Comment: @Modo It's all already in there. When I run this page as .html page, it works fine

Comment: Can you please edit the question and post the entire contents of the ```<head>...</head>```?

Comment: @Modo there it is

Comment: @Modo sorry, I just changed html file, please, if you saw fisrt version, copy it again.

Comment: Try this and let me know if it works : ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">```

Comment: @Modo, unfortunately, it does not help. Actually, I already had that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using jsp tag inside href attribute in link tag.
So I changed the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
```

So, complete code from the answer should be as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background: #000514;">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Dashboard - Logiweb Brand</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css"/>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css"/>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="assets/fonts/fontawesome5-overrides.min.css"/>">
</head>

<body id="page-top" style="background: rgb(0,0,0);">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content-wrapper" style="background: #000514;">
            <div class="text-break text-left" id="content" style="background: #000514;"></div>
        </div><a class="border rounded d-inline scroll-to-top" href="#page-top"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" style="color: var(--pink);background: #d70884;">
        <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="#">First Item</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Second Item</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Third Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">Dropdown </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">First Item</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second Item</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Third Item</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/theme.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```